# How are the Constructor and Destructors called

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

```
#include<iostream>


class Example{
    int i=0,j=0;
    public:
        Example(){
            std::cout<<"Default Constructor is called "<<j++<<std::endl;
        }
        ~Example(){
            std::cout<<"Destructor is Called "<<i++<<std::endl;
        }
        void display(){
            std::cout<<"Display method called "<<std::endl;
        }
};

void function(){
    Example e;
    e.display();
}

int main(){

 function();
Example e1;

}
```

I'm trying to see how the constructor and destructor are called for two objects of the same class

The output I'm getting is

```
Default Constructor is called 0
Display method is called
Destructor is called 0
Default Constructor is called 0
Destructor is called 0
```

Why is my i and j variable not getting incremented

Comment: Your variables are incremented, but you don't print the new value.

Comment: Try `++j` and `++i`.  And maybe (depending on your intentions) declare them `static`.

Comment: Once you change from post to pre increment, note that each object will have its own copy of the member variables, and that both objects member variables will be initialized to the same value: Zero.

Answer (score 3):

Your `i` and `j` variables are incremented, but the results are not printed.

You used postfix increment operator, so it is evaluated to the value *before* incrementing.

As you say, there are *two objects*, and they have independend member variables `i` and `j` because they are not static.

Answer (score 0):

Since both the objects are independent of each other so incremented values will not affect another object. They are incrementing , if you want to see the incremented value then you can try pre-increment by using ++i or ++j instead of i++ or j++.
To know more you comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different objects of class **Example** namely `e` and `e1`. Where `e` belongs to your defined `function` function, and `e1` belongs to the `main` function.

So when you execute your program, object `e` only gets called once and the values of `i` and `j` get incremented for that object. But then you use another object `e1`, for which their values different than previously called object `e`. That's why values of `i` and `j` are different for different objects. Every time you create a new object, they get initialized to 0 for that object.

Now, what you have to do to make these values same for all objects is to make those variables `static`. Static will make variables accessible to all objects you create of same class with unchanged value and they don't get initialize every time you create a new object.

Here is how you can do it:

```cpp
static int i,j;
```

But make sure you don't initialize static variables inside class. Otherwise program will throw an error. So, to initialize your static variables to 0, access them outside of class and set them to whatever value you wish to initialize them with. Like following:

```cpp
int Example::i = 0;
int Example::j = 0;
```

That's it. Now you can achieve what you were looking for.

So now your code must look something like this:

```cpp
class Example{
    static int i,j;
    public:
        Example(){
            std::cout<<"Default Constructor is called "<<j++<<std::endl;
        }
        ~Example(){
            std::cout<<"Destructor is Called "<<i++<<std::endl;
        }
        void display(){
            std::cout<<"Display method called "<<std::endl;
        }
};

int Example::i = 0;
int Example::j = 0;

void function(){
    Example e;
    e.display();
}

int main(){
 function();
 Example e1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change has been made. Please run this again

```
#include<iostream>


class Example{
    static int i,j; //Changed
    public:
        Example(){
            std::cout<<"Default Constructor is called "<<j++<<std::endl;
        }
        ~Example(){
            std::cout<<"Destructor is Called "<<i++<<std::endl;
        }
        void display(){
            std::cout<<"Display method called "<<std::endl;
        }
};
int Example::i = 0; //initializing i and j like this outside the class
int Example::j = 0; //Added

void function(){
    Example e;
    e.display();
}

int main(){

 function();
Example e1;

}
```